# Composition of dominant rational maps is dominant

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:V\dashrightarrow W$ and $g:W\dashrightarrow X$ be two rational dominant maps of affine varieties, where dominant means $f(\mathrm{dom} \, f)$ dense in $W$ ang $g(\mathrm{dom} \, g)$ dense in $X$, with respect to Zariski topology. How can be proved that the composition $g\circ f$ is also dominant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $U\subseteq X$ is open and nonempty then $V:=g^{-1}(U)$ is nonempty ($g$ dominant) and open (rational maps are Zariski-continuous), then $f^{-1}(V)$ nonempty ($f$ dominant), hence in total $(g\circ f)^{-1}(U)$ nonempty, i.e. $g\circ f$ dominant.

Comment: How does being dominant imply that $g^{-1}(U)\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the converse, why $g^{-1}(U)\neq\emptyset$ implies that $g$ is dominant? (In this case applied to $g\circ f$)

Comment: Maybe a late response, but for the sake of completeness: if $(g \circ f)^{-1}(U) \neq \emptyset$, this implies that im$(g \circ f) \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Since this holds for all open and non-empty $U \subseteq X$, the image must be dense, hence dominant